# how to make tablayout transparent on image slider

Tags: android, android-tablayout

how to make tab layout transparent on image slider...here is my layout where i declared tab layout...i searched lot but i don't got any solution for this...

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="#db000000"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#EF9C1A"
        android:tabStripEnabled="true"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[like in this image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZYP9.jpg)

[my app is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUM7o.png)

Comment: Please provide your MainActivity code where you declared tabLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it's `android:background` to `#70000000`. This will make it semi transparent. Just change the `70` value to something that fits you better. 99 is darken. 10 is transparent (lighter)

**Edit:** For making it completely transparent just use `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: So you want it completely transparent? From the picture "like in this image" it's semi transparent so I thought.. by the way just set the background color to @android:color/transparent

Comment: That's because your layout is white and your image isn't in it's back side. You need to adjust it's position. To check if it's really transparent you can try to change your RelativeLayout color to any color and see if tablayout color is also changing.

Comment: i got it but the thing is my slider comes over the tab layout...and it hides my tab layout..can you help me with this problem

Comment: ya it was the same problem like you said

Comment: Set your tablayout's android:elevation="2";

Comment: If the elevation doesn't bring the tablayout to the top than you can try the following schema: In your root layout (RelativeLayout) you have the image slider and tablayout. Just move the tab layout's code to the bottom in your RelativeLayout. So: <RelativeLayout><ImageSlide></ImageSlide><TabLayout></Tablayout></RelativeLayout>. Hope it helps :)